# InvalidOperationException in Sync Framework

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008-r2, microsoft-sync-framework

I have written a wrapper using Sync framework to provide a generic functionality.

This is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.Synchronization.Data;
using Microsoft.Synchronization.Data.SqlServer;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using Microsoft.Synchronization;


namespace PluginTest.Components
{
    public class P2PProvsionProvider
    {
        public SqlConnection RemoteConnection { get; set; }
        public SqlConnection LocalConnection { get; set; }
        private static Dictionary<string,DbSyncScopeDescription> scopes { get; set; }
        private static SqlSyncScopeProvisioning remoteProvision { get; set; }
        private static SqlSyncScopeProvisioning localProvision { get; set; }

        private static P2PProvsionProvider provider;

        //private P2PProvsionProvider() { 
        //}

        public P2PProvsionProvider() {
            scopes = new Dictionary<string, DbSyncScopeDescription>();
        }

        public static P2PProvsionProvider getInstance(string name) {
            if (name.Equals("default"))
                if (provider == null)
                    provider = new P2PProvsionProvider();
            return provider;
        }
        //1
        public void CreateProvisionScope(string name) {
            if (!scopes.ContainsKey(name))
            {
                scopes.Add(name, new DbSyncScopeDescription(name));
            }
        }

        //2
        public void AddProvisionTable(string scopeName, string tableName) {

            if (scopes[scopeName] != null)
            {
                DbSyncScopeDescription remoteScopeDesc = scopes[scopeName];
                //DbSyncScopeDescription localScopeDesc = scopes[scopeName];
                DbSyncTableDescription remoteTableDesc = SqlSyncDescriptionBuilder.GetDescriptionForTable(tableName, RemoteConnection);
                //DbSyncTableDescription localTableDesc = SqlSyncDescriptionBuilder.GetDescriptionForTable(tableName, LocalConnection);

                remoteScopeDesc.Tables.Add(remoteTableDesc);
                //localScopeDesc.Tables.Add(localTableDesc);

            }
        }

        //3
        public void ApplyScopeProvisioning (string scopeName){

            remoteProvision = new SqlSyncScopeProvisioning(RemoteConnection, scopes[scopeName]);
            remoteProvision.SetCreateProceduresDefault(DbSyncCreationOption.Skip);
            remoteProvision.Apply();

            localProvision = new SqlSyncScopeProvisioning(LocalConnection, scopes[scopeName]);
            localProvision.SetCreateProceduresDefault(DbSyncCreationOption.Skip);
            localProvision.Apply(); 

        }

        #region Scope Provisioning Builder methods
        public SqlSyncScopeProvisioning BuilderCreateProcedures(DbSyncCreationOption option)
        {
            remoteProvision.SetCreateProceduresDefault(option);
            return remoteProvision;
        }

        public SqlSyncScopeProvisioning BuilderCreateProceduresForAdditionalScope(DbSyncCreationOption option)
        {
            remoteProvision.SetCreateProceduresForAdditionalScopeDefault(option);
            return remoteProvision;
        }

        public SqlSyncScopeProvisioning BuilderCreateTable(DbSyncCreationOption option)
        {
            remoteProvision.SetCreateTableDefault(option);
            return remoteProvision;
        }

        public SqlSyncScopeProvisioning BuilderCreateTrackingTable(DbSyncCreationOption option)
        {
            remoteProvision.SetCreateTrackingTableDefault(option);
            return remoteProvision;
        }

        public SqlSyncScopeProvisioning BuilderCreateTriggers(DbSyncCreationOption option)
        {
            remoteProvision.SetCreateTriggersDefault(option);
            return remoteProvision;
        }

        public SqlSyncScopeProvisioning BuilderPopulateTrackingTable(DbSyncCreationOption option)
        {
            remoteProvision.SetPopulateTrackingTableDefault(option);
            return remoteProvision;
        }

        public SqlSyncScopeProvisioning BuilderUseBulkProcedures(bool useBulk)
        {
            remoteProvision.SetUseBulkProceduresDefault(useBulk);
            return remoteProvision;
        }
        #endregion
        //4


        public SyncOperationStatistics ExecuteSync(string scopeName , SyncDirectionOrder direction = SyncDirectionOrder.UploadAndDownload) {

            SyncOrchestrator syncOrachestrator = new SyncOrchestrator() {
                LocalProvider = new SqlSyncProvider(scopeName, LocalConnection),
                RemoteProvider = new SqlSyncProvider(scopeName, RemoteConnection), 
                Direction = direction 
            };

            ((SqlSyncProvider)syncOrachestrator.LocalProvider).ApplyChangeFailed += (s,e) =>
            {

            };

            return syncOrachestrator.Synchronize();
        }

        //5 Deprovision certain scope
        public void DeprovisionScope(SqlConnection conn, string scopeName) {
            SqlSyncScopeDeprovisioning deprovisionScope = new SqlSyncScopeDeprovisioning(conn);
            deprovisionScope.DeprovisionScope(scopeName);
        }

        //6 Deprovision All
        public void DeprovisionStore(SqlConnection conn)
        {
            SqlSyncScopeDeprovisioning deprovisionScope = new SqlSyncScopeDeprovisioning(conn);
            deprovisionScope.DeprovisionStore();
        }
    }
}
```

As the question suggest I am getting an InvalidOperationException saying that Saying that some stored procedure does not exist.
The app works as follows:
provided the following definition in the Form

```
    public GlobalFramework.Core core { get; set; }
    public BindingList<string> addedTables { get; set; }
    public BindingList<string> provisionedTables { get; set; }
    public P2PProvsionProvider provider { get; set; }
    public SyncOperationStatistics stats { get; set; }
```

1- When the user clicks on a button with "Add Provision Scope" text the following is done:

```
private void provisionButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        provider.CreateProvisionScope(provisionScopeTextBox.Text);
        foreach (var item in provisionedTables)
        {
            provider.AddProvisionTable(provisionScopeTextBox.Text, item);
        }

    }
```

2- When the user clicks on the button with "Apply Provision" the following is done

```
private void applyProvisionButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        provider.ApplyScopeProvisioning(provisionScopeTextBox.Text);
    }
```

3- When the user clicks on the  button with "Synchronize" the following is done

```
private void syncButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        stats = provider.ExecuteSync(provisionScopeTextBox.Text);
        statsLabel.Text = "Start time: " + stats.SyncStartTime + "End Time: " +stats.SyncEndTime+ "Change Total: "+stats.DownloadChangesTotal; 
    }
```

Now I am wondering why do I keep getting this Exception?
My local database connection is SQL Server 2008 R2.
My remote database is SQL Server 2008 R2 too.

P.S: I know that I should only provision the scope once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why are you skipping creation of stored procedures?

remoteProvision.SetCreateProceduresDefault(DbSyncCreationOption.Skip);
localProvision.SetCreateProceduresDefault(DbSyncCreationOption.Skip);

you should only be skipping the creation if you know the tables has been previously provisioned and they already have stored procs created.

Comment: Thx. Now I am using the CreateOrUseExisiting option.